# Extjs3.3.0 numberfield

Tags: extjs3

The window contain a form which including `NumberField(allowBlank: false)`, as soon as you open the window the `NumberField` is outlined in red. saying the field is required. but we hope the `NumberField` should not be outlined in red unless the user clicks the filed and clicks away without entering anything. how to config this `NumberField`.

extjs library: 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do. 
Basically I listen to 'focus'/'blur' event and if value is blank, call markInvalid, otherwise clearInvalid.

```
                        xtype : 'numberfield',
                        fieldLabel :'number',
                        markNumberInvalid : function(){
                            if(this.getValue() == ""){
                                this.markInvalid();
                            }else{
                                this.clearInvalid();
                            }   
                        },
                        listeners : {
                            'focus' : function(){
                                this.markNumberInvalid();
                            },
                            'blur' : function(){
                                this.markNumberInvalid();
                            }
                        }
```